# Sqoop export failing for foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I have a table A in hive (dump taken from mysql) which contain following row, 1st column being ID which is PK.

```
1295517534, 112,    Harshal-test,   2016-04-14 10:13:32,    2016-04-15 05:17:30,    NULL,   NULL,   NULL
1295517533, 112,    "3tLMPU9Ii7ObvATtF1j6d8Hnla-15n5zMcWTDUKgC54,   2016-04-14 10:13:32,    2016-04-15 05:17:30,    NULL,   NULL,   NULL
```

I have another table B which contain record something like below of which 1st and 3rd column are start and end and they both are FK refering to ID of table A.

```
1,  1,  1,  1,  2016-04-15 05:17:30,    2016-04-15 05:17:30
1295517533, 1,  1,  1,  2016-04-15 05:17:30,    2016-04-15 05:17:30
1295517533, 1,  1295517534, 1,  2016-04-15 05:17:30,    2016-04-15 05:17:30
```

When I try to export these records to MYSQL, SQOOP job fails for foreign key issue. for e.g. record 1, has start and end values as 1 which are not present in Parent table, record 2 has start value present in parent table but end value is not present. But since for record 3 start and end values both are present in parent table that row should be exported to mysql.

How can I write a hive query that will select only those records in table B which have start and end values present in parent table?

Or is there any other way to disable FK in mysql before importing using SQOOP?

I tried disabling FK by setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 in mysql but SQOOP job is still failing.

Child Table:
    CREATE TABLE `edges` (
      `start` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `end` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `base_strength` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      db_updated datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `lookup` (`start`,`type`,`end`),
      UNIQUE KEY `reverse_lookup` (`end`,`type`,`start`),
      CONSTRAINT `edges_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`start`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `edges_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`end`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Parent table

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `useragent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_seen` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `akaid_index` (`type`,`name`),
  KEY `useragent_idx` (`useragent`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `useragentfk` FOREIGN KEY (`useragent`) REFERENCES `useragents` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1091725696 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways.

Drop FOREIGN constrain ,

load data and

re create constrain .

or

Disable constrain using

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

insert your data

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Comment: Table is around 400gb so if i drop constraint and rebuild it, it takes ages and eventually fails. I tried 2nd method also but it seems sqoop opens new connection for each mapper and doesn't recognise FK check is disabled

Comment: i am not sure how scoop works but if you could try second option in each query ......